# Including server tags within javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, highcharts

I have created a highchart using the following:

```
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var name = document.getElementById('txtTest').value;
alert(name);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Users per lesson'
    },
       xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Users'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Lessons',
        data: [

                ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});

</script>

<div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I can get the graph to output, but as you can see: the "data" field in my javascript is empty. I am trying to insert a string into here which is taken into the session. If i apply the attribute to a textbox this works fine:

```
<input type="text" id="txtTest" class="txtTest" value="<%= session.getAttribute("jsTag") %>" />
```

If i try to add it to my script like the below it does not work:

```
data: [
        <%
        session.getAttribute("jsTag");    
        %>
    ],
```

My question is, can i not include jsp tags within javascript? if so, how could i change this so this works?

Btw - `session.getAttribute("jsTag");` outputs as `['Column1', 1]`

Comment: Did you try `data : <% session.getAttribute("jsTag"); %>` ? Check also the [api](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data) for the data format.

Comment: @Core972 - whilst inspecting it, it does not output anything at all so it's not the square brackets which are wrong. It seems as though I can't inject jsp into script tags?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to cover <%= session.getAttribute("jsTag") %> with  ' ' .

```
data: [
        '<%=session.getAttribute("jsTag")%>'
    ],
```

Comment: When doing this way, i get an error saying  " ')' expected, illegal start of expression"

Answer (score 0):

use 
**<%= session.getAttribute("jsTag"); %>**

also always put it in quotes, otherwise if the value rendered from backend if null, it will throw JS exception.

Comment: When doing this way, i get an error saying  " ')' expected, illegal start of expression"